# Is it possible to accept post dated payments online?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment

I was just wondering if there is a way today to accept future-dated payments online, similar to what offline post-dated checks do.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you essentially need to store the transaction information and then process it on the day desired. There's two ways to do this:

1. You store the transaction information and run a cron job daily that looks for these scheduled transactions and processes them when they are ready to be paid.
2. You use a third party to store the information and run a cron job daily that looks for these scheduled transactions and processes them when they are ready to be paid.

Option 1 is **not** recommended for PCI compliance and security reasons. Option 2 is achievable using a service like [Authorize.Net's Customer Information Manager (CIM)](http://welcome.authorize.net/cim/) which allows you to create payment profiles and then charge against them at a future date. This **is** recommended as it makes you PCI compliant and less of a target to hackers.

Either way to need to build your own scheduled task to check for when these payments are due and charge them accordingly but that isn't rocket surgery.